# How to Install Modules like SQLite and CORS on GCloud App

Tags: python, flask, import, cloud, gcloud

I recently am trying to deploy my Google App and I keep getting the error:

**Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.**

The Error logs usually point out that modules are not imported (such as SQLite3, CORS). More directly:

```
ImportError: No module named _sqlite3 at <module> 
(/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/174489198b39d9fb/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py:28)
     at <module> (/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/174489198b39d9fb/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/__init__.py:24)
     at <module> (/base/data/home/apps/d~project/20200707t163255.427927458963207305/models.py:1)
     at <module> (/base/data/home/apps/d~project/20200707t163255.427927458963207305/main.py:3)
```

```
ImportError: No module named flask_cors
     at <module> (/base/data/home/apps/d~project/20200707t145904.427925946907808635/main.py:2)
```

How do I import these modules?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is this Google App Engine? if yes, can you add app.yaml file? does it work locally?